# Can using a VPN on my phone change my location when Okta requests a passcode via SMS?

Tags: geolocation, single-sign-on, okta, okta-signin-widget

I prefer not to disclose my location to Okta. When logging in, Okta requests a passcode via SMS. If I use a VPN on my phone, will it alter my location for this purpose?

I attempted to set up a VPN on my phone, expecting it to display a different location. To confirm if this approach works, I need verification from Okta experts.

Comment: Depends on your VPN setup (what public IP address your VPN assigns you). But, if you don't (want to) trust your identity provider, you have much bigger problems.